# Increase memory in Jboss eap 5.1

Tags: jboss, jvm-arguments

I' m using **Jboss-eap-5.1**. when I trying to **change memory** parameters through **run.conf.bat**, it is **not change**. when I run the server after doing changes i saw through **Java Visual VM**, changes are  not applied. How can I change the memory sizes in Jboss-eap-5.1

> This shows you how I do the changes (JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Before run the server through run.bat command need to run the run.conf.bat file. Then system will initialize the parameters in run.conf.bat file